# $f=g+ih$ is $L^p$ if and only if $g$ and $h$ are $L^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $X$ be a measure space, $f:X\to\mathbb{C}$ a measurable function, and $1<p<\infty$.
$f$ is said to be $L^p$ if $|f|^p$ is integrable.
Now, let $f=g+ih$, where $g$ and $h$ are real-valued. Is $f$ $L^p$ if and only if $g$ and $h$ are $L^p$ ? If not, is there any relationship between these two conditions?

Comment: $L^p$ is a vector space, so if $g, h \in L^p$ then any linear combination must be in $L^p$. I'm not sure about the other direction though. My intuition says no, but I can't justify it just yet.

Comment: $|g|\leq |f|$ and  $|h| \leq |g|$.

Comment: @geetha290krm typo: $|h|\leq |f|$.

Comment: Right. I meant to say $|h| \leq |f| $. Thanks,  @peek-a-boo

Comment: $|g|^p+|h|^p\le 2|f|^p\le 2^{p+1}(|g|^p+|h|^p).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$. By Holder's inequality  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Notable_special_cases,  for all $x \in X$, we have
$$ \max\{|g(x)|^p, |h(x)|^p \} \le |f(x)|^p \le (|g(x)|+|h(x)|)^p \le 2^{p/q}\cdot (|g(x)|^p+|h(x)|^p) \,.$$
Integrating over $x \in X$ proves the desired equivalence.